# Generator methods, deepcopy and copy

Tags: python, generator, deep-copy

I am trying to avoid the use of deepcopy in a custom class (a Graph class)

The graphs have few attributes, such as vertices, edges, etc. and several generator methods (methods with `yield`).

I need to copy the graph: e.g.  `H = deepcopy(G)` but not using deepcopy in order to speed up the program.

Then:

- If I do not use `deepcopy` then the
  generator methods in the new graph `H`
  do not get the current state of the
  generator methods in graph `G`.
- If I do not use generator methods and
  opt for using full list generator,
  then I will waste computation time
  doing nothing useful.

The solution was to try to `deepcopy` some specific generator methods, but I get errors.

It seems that the generators save references to, e.g. the vertices and edges of `G` and then when deepcopied to `H` the generators in `H` are still referencing the attributes of `G` (this sounds logical).

So, am I condemned to use `deepcopy` after all or not use generator methods?

Is there a third pythonic way?

Comment: Show us some (pseudo)code, this is too abstract (at least for me).

Comment: You can't copy generators, simple as that. So this question makes no sense o me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I also don't think the question makes no sense. If you want to copy everything, then use deep copy. If you don't need to copy everything, then tell what you don't need to copy.

Comment: @Jochen, I agree. @rafalotufo, @Jose, I think Jochen's point is that the problem can't have anything to do with the generators themselves, unless Jose is calling generators and storing them without iterating over them, which would be unusual.

Comment: the point of my comment being, please post some code so that we can understand the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure I understand what you're getting at. Here's a simple example:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes):
        self.nodes = list(nodes)
        self.nodegen = self.iternodes()
    def iternodes(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
            yield node
    def copy(self):
        return Graph(self.nodes)

G = Graph([1, 2, 3, 4])
print G.nodegen.next()
H = G.copy()
print H.nodegen.next()
print G.nodegen.next()
```

Now of course this will print `1 1 2`. You, however, want `H.nodegen` to remember the state of `G.nodegen` so that the call to `H.nodegen.next()` prints 2. A simple way is to make them the same object:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes, nodegen=None):
        self.nodes = list(nodes)
        self.nodegen = self.iternodes() if nodegen is None else nodegen
    def iternodes(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
            yield node
    def copy(self):
        return Graph(self.nodes, self.nodegen)
```

This will print `1 2 3`, since calling `H.nodegen.next()` will advance `G.nodegen` as well. If that's not what you want, it seems fine to me to keep an internal counter, like this:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes, jnode=0):
        self.nodes = list(nodes)
        self.nodegen = self.iternodes()
        self.jnode = jnode
    def iternodes(self):
        while self.jnode < len(self.nodes):
            self.jnode += 1
            yield self.nodes[self.jnode-1]
    def copy(self):
        return Graph(self.nodes, self.jnode)
```

This will print `1 2 2`, which I suspect is what you want. Of course you'll have to change how you take care of things like invalidating iterators when you change `self.nodes`, but I think it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Hi @Cosmologicon, yes this is the sense of the question. It seems that the solution for me is to invalidate the iterators causing the problem since I am deleting vertices and adding edges to the graph H. I use more complex iterators such as iterating over the triangles of the graph and other special subgraphs and also have iterators for the edges which are frozen sets. So if iterators keep references to vertices and edges I will be in troubles.

Comment: how can I reser or invalidate such generator method?

Comment: The iterator will become invalid by itself. That just means it shouldn't be used anymore. The question is how do you detect this and take the appropriate steps to avoid using it. That depends completely on how you're using it in the first case. At this point I agree that you should post some code.